# My output is not rounding correctly and it doesn't match the expected output

Tags: java

sorry if this is an obvious question but I just started learning computer science.

I have to print the results of this with 14 decimal places so I did so by using %.14f in a printf statement. All of the other variables are integers

```
double caloriesBurnedW = 0.0175 * 4 * (weight/2.2) * walkingTime; 
double caloriesBurnedR = 0.0175 * 10 * (weight/2.2) * runningTime;
double caloriesBurnedMC = 0.0175 * 8 * (weight/2.2) * mountainClimberTime;
```

The outputs I get are

- 286.36363636363640
- 114.54545454545455
- 229.09090909090910

but they should be

- 286.3636363636364
- 114.54545454545456
- 229.09090909090912

Comment: If you need precision use `BigDecimal` .

Comment: Also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: @PM77-1 I tried doing this but I still get the same values `BigDecimal caloriesBurnedW = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.0175 * 4 * (weight/2.2) * walkingTime);
  BigDecimal caloriesBurnedR = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.0175 * 10 * (weight/2.2) * runningTime);
  BigDecimal caloriesBurnedMC = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.0175 * 8 * (weight/2.2) * mountainClimberTime);
 `

Comment: Then your "*should be*" numbers are wrong.

Comment: @PM77-1 They're straight from the assignment sheet though. It says that the program "must display the same information with the same format"

Comment: `286.3636363636364` has 13, not 14 decimals. The person who wrote the exercise appears to have done a basic `System.out.println(caloriesBurnedW);` and it just happened to result in this number of decimals (for weight=150, walkingTime=60). I would try that instead of direct formatting. I don't think this would have been an issue if the exercise author was more familiar with floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dividing the weight by 2.2, I created a variable

```
kgWeight = weight * (1/2.2)
```

That resolved the issue for some reason